# Automating tasks after vagrant ssh

Tags: bash, shell, vagrant, ansible

Wondering if it is possible to automatically run a script or execute a command ONLY after `vagrant ssh` into the box? I understand that [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) can provide beforehand installation and set up. But it failed to allow doing things automatically after entering the machine.

I am currently create a file `script.sh`. The file will be provided to the vagrant via Ansible. After I `vagrant ssh` into the box, I do `bash script.sh` to run the script. Is there better way?

Any suggestion would be more appreciated.

Comment: Tack `bash script.sh` at the end of `~/.bashrc` i.e. do `echo 'bash script.sh' >>~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways to achieve this,

Say assume your script is in vagrant home directory like,

```
:~$/home/vagrant/test-me.sh
```

1) Run command along with ssh

```
1a) vagrant ssh -- -t '/home/vagrant/test-me.sh; /bin/bash'

**-OR-**

1b) vagrant ssh -c '/home/vagrant/test-me.sh; /bin/bash'
```

2) Append complete script path in ~/.bashrc file (this should be in vagrant home directory if you are login as user vagrant)

```
:~$echo '. /home/vagrant/test-me.sh' >> ~/.bashrc
```